# Zend framework user authentication integration with Twitter and Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, zend-framework, twitter, openid

Is there any script based on ZF, which supports normal user signup/login system, along with user authentication throuh Twitter and Facebook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [An example of OpenID, Facebook and Twitter authentication in Zend Framework 1.11](http://shortrecipes.blogspot.com/2011/02/example-of-openid-facebook-and-twitter.html). Altough, the application does not show how to use normal user authentication (it was not the purpose of it) it shows one way of using OpenID (Google,
Yahoo, MyOpenId, AOL, OpenId) as well as Facebook Connect and Twitter Oauth for
authentication of users. This is more difficult to do in ZF than regular user authentication.

Comment: can you elaborate this example. As I tried it with tweeter.com, it always shows 'Redirection Failed', you are not logged in. Demo url is : http://articlecon.com/phpdemo/tf/

Comment: @Simpanoz. Maybe your url is not correct. For example, in my appkeys.ini, url for twitter is twitter.redirecturi = http://www.mwol.born2die.eu/zfopenid/public/user/login/

Answer (score 4):

Don't know about twitter but you can use the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) easily enough in a ZF project. There's an excellent example in the SDK "examples" folder.

My approach is to

- Add the Facebook object as an application resource plugin, eg

---

```
require_once 'facebook.php';

class My_Application_Resource_Facebook extends Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract
{
    public function init()
    {
        $facebook = new Facebook($this->getOptions());

        Zend_Registry::set('facebook', $facebook);

        return $facebook;
    }
}
```

---

- Check the Facebook session and user in your `Bootstrap.php` file, adding it to `Zend_Auth` if applicable
- Include the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) in your layout
- Use the [Login Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/) to authenticate your users

Because the Facebook auth token is cookie based, both your server-side code and client-side JS can access it.

**Edit** Twitter libraries here - http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php