# How can i create openID script for Google, Facebook, Twitter using Zend framework Php?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am doing in office Zend Framework which is a PHP framework. Already with database we have a small application running. But we want to implement new login method. Where we would allow user to login with there Google or Facebook or Twitter accounts, after the validation we will accept it.

I thought it was available with Zend Framework, but i cant find any working example for such with framework or wihtout. Is it possible for someone to provide any example with Php or Zend Framework such?

Looking forward to hear from you.

Many thanks

Comment: Did you tried Zend_OpenId or OpenAuth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this one: [Zend framework user authentication integration with Twitter and Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175846/zend-framework-user-authentication-integration-with-twitter-and-facebook)